# jQueryで値変更を検知する方法について教えて下さい

Tags: jquery

jQueryを最近使い始めた者です。

jQueryでテキストボックスAの値が変更された時（入力ではなく）に、
別のテキストボックスBを初期化したいのですが、こうした時、普通は、
Aの値を変えた時に、

```
$('#fld_A').val('12345').change();
```

というように敢えてイベントを発生させて入力した時と同じように

```
$('#fld_A').on('change', function(){
    $('#fld_B').val('');
}
```

と書けば、Bの値を変更できる、とは思うのですが、

Aの値をセットする処理が、フォームを作成するツール(intramart-FormaDedigner)の中のパーツで組み込まれているために触ることが出来ない状態にあります。

`change();`を使わずに、Aが変わったことを検知する方法は無いでしょうか？
ちなみに、Aが変わる時には、ダイヤログを呼び出すためのアイコンがクリックされるので、そのイベントは取れるとは思いますが、処理をキャンセルしてAが変わらないケースもあるため、その判別ができません。

よい方法がありましたら、アドバイス頂けると幸いです。

Comment: ダイアログを呼び出すイベントは検知できるとのことですが、ダイアログを閉じるイベントは検知できますか？

Comment: コメント有難うございます。ダイヤログの中身はツールの提供するコンポーネントに制御が移ってしまうため、内容を検知が出来ないと思います。

Comment: 触ることができない、という状況がよくわかりません。
処理を実装しようとしているスクリプトが属するdocument内のiframe内にAが存在するということでしょうか？

Comment: コメント有難うございます。処理を実装しようとするフォーム内のイベントで、Framework（内部仕様非公開）の提供するプログラムが呼び出され、別のダイヤログが表示されて、さらにその中のイベントでAが変更されてているからです。